# How do I get a list of symbolic links, excluding broken links?

Tags: unix, symlink

I have been able to find a command to get a list of the broken links only, but not the "working" symbolic links

```
find -H mydir -type l
```

How can I do the opposite?

If I have these files in `mydir`:

```
foo
bar
bob
carol
```

If they are all symbolic links, but `bob` points to a file that doesn't exist, I want to see

```
foo
bar
carol
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `find(1)` use

```
$ find . -type l -not -xtype l
```

This command finds links that stop being links after following - that is, unbroken links. (Note that they may point to ordinary or special files, directories or other. Use `-xtype f` instead of `-not -xtype l` to find only links pointing to ordinary files.)

```
$ find . -type l -not -xtype l -ls
```

reports where they point to.

If you frequently encounter similar questions in your interactive shell usage, [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) is your friend:

```
% echo **/*(@^-@)
```

which follows the same idea: [Glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `@` restricts to links, and `^-@` means "not (`^`) a link (`@`) when following is enabled (`-`).

(See also [this post about finding broken links in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794/), actually this demonstrates what you can do in all languages under Linux. See [this blog post](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Shell/How%20to%20find%20broken%20symlinks.futile) for a complete answer to the related question of "how to find *broken* links".)

Answer (score 2):

This will show (LINUX) only symbolic links that are links to regular files that actually exist:

```
find DIR1 -type l -xtype f -ls
```

From the "find" (LINUX) documentation on the xtype option: "for symbolic links, -xtype checks the type of the file that -type does not check"

This option will show symbolic links to directories that actually exist:

```
find DIR1  -type l -xtype d -ls
```

Answer (score 1):

one bash solution:

```
find . -type l -print | while read src
do
    [[ -e "$src" ]] && echo $src
done
```

so, find all symlinks and check for the existence, if exists -> echo it