# How to override bad symlink with python

Tags: python, linux

```
[root@host]# ls -lad /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 May 11 19:51 /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf -> /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf/3.4.6
```

I have a smylink from `/etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf` point to `/etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf/3.4.6`
But `/etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf/3.4.6` doesn't exist.

So, when I run `ln -s /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf-3.4.6 /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf`, I get `ln: failed to access '/etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf': Too many levels of symbolic links`

1.How to build a smylink forcibly with `ln`?

2.How to decide whether a bad symlink is exist with python? If you run `os.path.exists(bad-link)`, you will get `False`

Comment: In future, please consider using separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question.

Because your logic is incorrect. The root cause is because you need to find the correct original file with version, instead of rebuilding the softlink.

Thus...

```
/etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf-3.4.6  <== is not exist

ln -s /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf-3.4.6 /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf <== this is not incorrect

#find the exist version zookeeper-conf-x.x.x
ln -s /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf-x.x.x /etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf <== this is correct
```

---

For your second question, this might use shell command(ls) to solve. `ls -L $symbolic_link` to check the that link is valid or not. It will print `No such file or directory` and return non-Zero value if the link's original file is not exist.

For example:

```
$ ls -al
symlink1 -> ./exist.txt
symlink2 -> ./not_exist.txt
exist.txt

$ ls -L symlink1
symlink1

$ ls -L symlink2
ls: symlink2: No such file or directory
```

Python command line solution

```
def check_symlink_exist(target_file):
    process = subprocess.Popen("ls -L " + target_file, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    return True if process.returncode == 0 else False
```

Python os solution

```
def check_symlink_exist(target_file):
    try:
        os.stat(target_file)
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this answer for detecting broken symlinks in Python: [Find broken symlinks with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794/find-broken-symlinks-with-python)

You should be able to `ln -sf` to force link generation, from the [ln man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html):

```
-f, --force  
remove existing destination files
```